# Azure: StorageException: The argument is out of range. CloudBlockBlob.CreateSnapshot()

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

Below is the method I've made to create a snapshot for all blobs in a container:

```
public static EmsStorageSnapshot CreateSnapshot(EmsStorageAccount storageAccount, EmsStorageContainer nContainer)
{
  try
  {
    DateTime snapDate = DateTime.Now;

    EmsStorageSnapshot snapshot = new EmsStorageSnapshot() { CreatedAt = snapDate, SnapshotReference = snapDate.ToString() };
    // var metadata = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "snapshotIssued", snapDate.ToString() } };

    CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(storageAccount.StorageAccountName, storageAccount.StorageAccountKey), false);

    var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var container = client.GetContainerReference(nContainer.ContainerName);

    List<CloudBlockBlob> blobs = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();

    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
      try
      {
        if (!blob.IsSnapshot)
        {
          var snapBlob = blob.CreateSnapshot();
          snapBlob.Metadata.Add("snapshotIssued", snapDate.ToString());
          snapBlob.SetMetadata();
        }
      }
      catch (StorageException ex)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to create a snapshot of blob {0}.", blob.Name);
        Logger.Log("Failed to create a snapshot of blob '" + blob.Name + "': " + ex.ToString(), VerboseLevel.Error);
      }
    }
    return snapshot;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Logger.Log(ex.ToString(), VerboseLevel.Error);
  }
  return null;
}
```

At the line ( var snapBlob = blob.CreateSnapshot(); ) i get the following error:

```
  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The argument is out of range. Value passed: 
  Parameter name: snapshot ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The argument is out of range. Value passed: 
  Parameter name: snapshot
     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.CommonUtility.ArgumentOutOfRange(String paramName, Object value) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\CommonUtility.cs:line 168
     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.NavigationHelper.ParseSnapshotTime(String snapshot) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Core\Util\NavigationHelper.cs:line 665
     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<>c__DisplayClass69.<CreateSnapshotImpl>b__68(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 3006
     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 711
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll version = 8.7.0.0

Comment: I just tried it with blobs in my storage account and I did not encounter any issues. Does your code fail on the very 1st blob in the list?

Comment: Yes it was the first one but i cant say if it was only the first one as i didnt step over the other blobs.

Answer (score 0):

I read the source code and found the exception was throw when you parses the snapshot time. You could refer to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Core/Util/NavigationHelper.cs).

```
internal static DateTimeOffset ParseSnapshotTime(string snapshot)
        {
            DateTimeOffset snapshotTime;
            if (!DateTimeOffset.TryParse(snapshot, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out snapshotTime))
            {
                CommonUtility.ArgumentOutOfRange("snapshot", snapshot);
            }
            return snapshotTime;
        }
```

I test in my local and it works well. So I suggest that you could try to test your code in local computer and use fiddler to check your x-ms-snapshot.

[image]

Also, as far as I know, you could not Set metadata after snapshoting. So you could refer to the following code to set metadata first and create snapshot.

```
Dictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();
metadata.Add("snapshotIssued", snapDate.ToString());
blob.CreateSnapshot(metadata);
```

Comment: Thank you for a well described answer, i will try to capture it with fiddler and update the question. I originally tried putting metadata into the CreateSnapshot method but had same result so i thought i was doing that wrong, at least i know i can revert back to that.